# Polygon Intersection with LineString (closed curve)

Tags: geopandas, shapely

I have a polygon as such

```
polygon_coords = [(-13585557.004033158, 4498795.070440721), (-13585215.14187693, 4500515.198409752), (-13581108.78850055, 4497863.34704348), (-13581192.612077117, 4497554.426176021), (-13580596.94148188, 4497528.496299017), (-13580385.211810393, 4497383.150012096), (-13579492.874772193, 4497412.443364113), (-13579516.36318475, 4497381.46809963), (-13579512.689641556, 4496699.194502575), (-13579497.884149278, 4495658.910722646), (-13579543.747779485, 4495404.005766705), (-13579528.051731283, 4493390.628219194), (-13581939.67717983, 4494259.602208199), (-13585136.884274904, 4495136.215086736), (-13585127.088159712, 4495209.923404868), (-13585108.943082713, 4497557.089248097), (-13585088.237657426, 4497826.48350398), (-13584837.546164159, 4498714.608439874), (-13585109.833638642, 4498744.185863254), (-13585477.18795826, 4498785.958859128), (-13585557.004033158, 4498795.070440721)]
polygon = Polygon(polygon_coords)
line_coords = [(-13581392.216297297, 4494641.272566045), (-13581395.793280436, 4494647.557676422)]

list(polygon.intersection(LineString(line_coords)).coords)

>>>  [(-13581392.216297297, 4494641.272566045), (-13581395.793280436, 4494647.557676422)]

list(polygon.intersection(LineString(line_coords + [line_coords[0]])).coords)

>>> [(-13581392.216297297, 4494641.272566045), (-13581395.793280436, 4494647.557676422)]
```

Intersection of `LineString(line_coords)` and `LineString(line_coords + [line_coords[0]])` gives the same result. I was expecting the intersection to have all the coordinates.. Am I missing something ?

Comment: it's n to really a "closed curve" / line ring as going from 2 points to 3 points doesn't change anything, a straight line from a to b as opposed to a straight line from a to b and from b to a

Comment: doesn't a LineString(a,b,a) become a closed curve ?

Comment: Not with only 3 points 2 of which are the same

Answer (score 0):

[`intersection`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.intersection) is a complex spatial operation, and shapely does not return the same object as is provided in the arguments, even if the intersecting objects are identical.

Seen here - even if we're just getting the intersection of the line with itself, shapely has returned a new object, though the coordinates are equal:

```py
In [13]: line = LineString(line_coords)

In [14]: hex(id(line))
Out[14]: '0x1041f1a50'

In [15]: hex(id(line.intersection(line)))
Out[15]: '0x10569b9d0'

In [16]: line == line.intersection(line)
Out[16]: True
```

Since the line (A, B, A) is equivalent in shape to (A, B), shapely will never return (A, B, A) from the intersection. There's also no reason why it wouldn't return (B, A) for `polygon.intersection(line)`, as the intersection has no concept of directionality.

Comment: ok, so a LineString is also a shape with area ?

Comment: @Rob Raymond is this what you are also suggesting as both LineStrings are exactly same geometrically eg: have same area on 2D; the intersecting is same i.e: the shortest ?